# sbt.build for multiple projects and playframework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt, sbt-plugin

Update:

So, the issue I'm trying to understand is why I can't have a `build.sbt` in the root folder. Even if I define a `lazy val root = ...` in the root `build.sbt` folder, the main class is not found.

This reddit link:

https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/4igc9x/sbt_playframework_no_main_class_detected/

suggests a solution to the problem. While `sbt demo/run` does execute the play app, I'd like to eventually just have `sbt run` from the root project compile and all the projects and then run the server.

Can anyone help out here?

=================================================================

Old question:

I'm trying to understand how build.sbt works, and I'm not sure what's going on. I'd like to build a play project as one of multiple projects being build under a root build.sbt file.

I have the following structure (most files left out for brevity):

```
.
|-- build.sbt
|-- project/
|   |-- build.properties
|   |-- plugins.sbt
|   |-- project/
|-- demo/
|   |-- build.sbt
|   |-- app/
|   |-- conf/
|   |    |-- application.conf
|   |    |-- routes
|   |-- public/
|   |-- test/
```

inside the root dir `build.sbt` file, I have the following.

```
name := "demo-root"
organization := "com.example"


scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.11.11"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .dependsOn(demo)
  .aggregate(demo)

lazy val demo = project
  .enablePlugins(PlayScala)
```

I've defined `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.14")` inside `plugins.sbt` in the root `project/`.

inside the `demo/build.sbt` I have

```
name := "demo"

version in ThisBuild := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

libraryDependencies += filters
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "2.0.0" % Test
```

Now, when I perform `sbt run`, I receive the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: No main class detected.
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last root/compile:run for the full output.
[error] (root/compile:run) No main class detected.
```

*However* if I put the root `build.sbt` and root `project/` inside of `demo/` and try to `sbt run`, the project compiles successfully and I can access the play server in the regular way.

Why is this error being thrown? Do I need to explicitly declare a main class for the play project in the root `build.sbt`? I'm following the instructions at http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Multi-Project.html, and I'm just a little lost. Any help in the right direction would be appreciated.

For reference ---

sbt version: 0.13.15

scala version: 2.11.11

play plugin version: 2.5.14

Comment: the `libraryDependencies` lines from the root `build.sbt` belong to `demo/build.sbt`, also you do not need to `.enablePlugins(PlayScala)` in the root `build.sbt` as you already do it in the `demo/build.sbt` (where it belongs). How is it going after changing those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no main class in the root project, only in the demo project.

When starting sbt in the root project, you have to use the following commands:

- `project demo`
- `run`

the equivalent one-line may be: `sbt demo/run`

To your updates, I don't know how to do that, I would advise against, and I'm pretty sure that's not something sbt will do out of the box for you.

Remember that there could be many sub-projects, each with their own main-class(es). In such situation, what would sbt be supposed to do?

An alternative would be to define the play project as the root/aggregate and have sub-projects there, as illustrated it the play doc: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/SBTSubProjects#Project-structure